# "Length of values does not match length of index" when extracting substring in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract daynumber from datetime column in a new column, like so

```py
df_merged['tr_date'] = df_merged['tr_datetime'].str.split(' ')[0]
```

When I run this code, I get the following error

> Length of values does not match length of index

Here is a sample of the `df_merged` data
[image: df_merged data]

Comment: First check the type of *df_merged['tr_datetime']*. If its str then directly use df_merged['tr_datetime'].split(' ')[1] or else use str(df_merged['tr_datetime']).split(' ')[1]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df_merged['tr_date'] = df_merged['tr_datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```

Comment: Thanks! The option that works for me is -  **df_merged['tr_day'] = str(df_merged['tr_datetime']).split(' ')[0]** - thanks @em_bis_me. but I still can't see why **df_merged['tr_datetime'].split(' ')[1] ** doesn't work(

Comment: Because when you take 0-th element, it is 0-th element of Series, not 0-th element of array which is element of this Series